# How to add a Wordpress post type that is password protected by default

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if anyone can advise me on how to create a custom Wordpress Post Type based on a page template that is password protected by default?

How do I go about doing this?

I have tried a few plugins such as "Custom Post Type UI" but cannot see how I add a page template or make the page password protected by default.

Thanks

Comment: You're asking 3 question in one. **1)** how to create a CPT. **2)** how to add a template. **3)** how to make it password protected. . . . Everything is possible, but you need to narrow each issue and show what efforts you took to solve it == ***`your code`***.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/
The plugin can block certain  types of pages by default.